Laravel fail to correctly generate URLs for static resources (Livewire 3, and others)
I’m encountering an issue with Laravel and Livewire when deploying my application on an Apache server. The problem arises when the application is hosted in a subfolder (e.g., domain.com/folder_app). The Livewire script generated by @livewireScripts creates a URL without the correct subfolder, causing the script to load from the root domain instead of the intended subdirectory.
In development (using php artisan serve), everything works fine, and the Livewire script loads correctly. However, in production, on the Apache server, the script is generated as:
<script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=38dc8241"   
data-csrf="iaZPc0e8Qbpo4PdpXkbBO3GYx21de4hAuXXifar7" 
data-update-uri="/livewire/update" 
data-navigate-once="true"></script>

This points to domain.com/livewire/livewire.js instead of domain.com/folder_app/livewire/livewire.js.
What I’ve tried so far:
Set APP_URL in the .env file to include the subfolder, like so:
APP_URL=https://example.com/folder_app

Modified config/livewire.php to include asset_url:
return [
'asset_url' => env('LIVEWIRE_ASSET_URL', '/folder_app'),
];

Added LIVEWIRE_ASSET_URL=/folder_app to the .env file.
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

public function boot()
{
    if (config('app.env') !== 'local') {
        URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }

    Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
        return Route::get('/custom/livewire/livewire.js', $handle)->name('livewire.asset');
    });
}

This function Livewire::setScriptRoute() helped me set the script URL correctly, but it didn't fix the return URL (data-update-uri="/livewire/update") which is also generated incorrectly.
Cleared all caches using php artisan route:clear, config:clear, cache:clear, etc.
The issue:
Even with these configurations, Livewire still generates the script URL without the subfolder on the Apache server. In development, the correct URL is used. What else do I need to configure so Livewire generates the correct script path when the app is deployed on Apache in a subdirectory?
Any advice on how to fix this routing issue?

!!! SEEE NEW ANSWER !!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79293747/broken-links-in-laravel-on-windows-issues-with-storage-livewire-and-ipv6-link/79293748#79293748

I am applying this FIX because, for some unknown reason, PHP and Laravel fail to correctly generate URLs for static resources. This is not the best solution, but it ensures the application works as intended until the root cause of the issue is identified and resolved.
php artisan make:middleware ModifyOutputMiddleware

source:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ModifyOutputMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    // Continue with the request to get the original response
    $response = $next($request);

    // Check if the response is HTML to modify it
    if ($response->headers->get('Content-Type') === 'text/html; charset=UTF-8') {
        $content = $response->getContent();

        $urlBase = asset('/');

        // Get the base URL 
        $content = str_replace(
            [
                'data-update-uri="/',
                'src="/',
                'href="/'
            ],
            [
                'data-update-uri="'.$urlBase,
                'src="'.$urlBase,
                'href="'.$urlBase
            ],
            $content
        );

        $response->setContent($content);
    }

    return $response;
}
}

Add the middleware to laravel 11 in file bootstrap/app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {

        $middleware->append(\App\Http\Middleware\ModifyOutputMiddleware::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Make sure you config correctly your .env file at APP_URL

I now understand why Laravel files fail on Windows...
The issue is the file format; they are not consistently formatted between Windows and Linux, which causes errors on Windows. I tested it with Laravel's Herb, and everything worked fine.
It's best to install everything on Linux, in Docker containers, or with Herb. herb page
it's the routes. The scripts fail on Windows when they come from Linux, and that breaks everything during compilations. I installed a project with Herb, and everything works perfectly. Even compiled routes from Orchid, Livewire, and Jetstream fail on Windows, but if you set them up in a Linux environment, they work fine.
For Windows, Herb is the solution. Check it out, and you'll see that nothing fails with it!
