Broken Links in Laravel on Windows: Issues with Storage, Livewire, and IPv6 Links
I am encountering several issues with Laravel's handling of links when using Windows as the operating system. Here are the problems I've identified:
Broken Links in Laravel Paqueterías:
Many Laravel packages generate broken links when deployed in a Windows environment. This includes issues with Livewire generating [::] (IPv6 shorthand) links, which are not correctly resolved.
Problems with php artisan storage:link:
The php artisan storage:link command fails to generate proper symbolic links in Windows. Instead of functioning links, incorrect routes are produced, breaking the functionality of the storage directory.
General Route Issues:
Other routing-related issues arise due to Windows' lack of native support for certain types of symbolic links (correct me if the term is different).
Root Cause:
The main problem lies in Windows’ incomplete support for Unix-style symbolic links. Laravel relies heavily on these links for features like php artisan storage:link and routing mechanisms. Without proper support, the system generates invalid links and routing errors.
Before understand the error:
Laravel fail to correctly generate URLs for static resources (Livewire 3, and others)

Proposed Solution:
To resolve this, the best approach is to set up a development environment that closely mirrors a production-like Linux system. Using WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) provides a robust way to achieve this.
Steps to Fix the Issues:
Install WSL2
Follow the official WSL installation guide to enable and configure WSL2 on your Windows system. Install a Linux distribution like Ubuntu.
Set Up the Development Environment in WSL2:

Install PHP-FPM (PHP 8.3 recommended)
Install composer
Install Nginx
Install MySQL
Install Node.js and npm
Install the Laravel Installer

Execute commands like (inside on your new laravel app):
php artisan storage:link

within the WSL2 environment to ensure symbolic links are created properly
Verify Functionality:
Test your Laravel application by accessing routes and checking storage links to confirm that the issues have been resolved.
